# Swap two keyboard Keys

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a program in "C#", which when I type the "Enter" key, it will act as if "Tab" was typed, and the program will run in the state where the window is Minimized.
Sorry for typos, I wrote this text with a translator

I used the following code:

```
private void treeView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  /* If the 'Alt' and 'E' keys are pressed,
   * allow the user to edit the TreeNode label. */
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Thanks!");
  }
}
```

And the result I wanted was not achieved

Comment: Tip: it is just a few registry tweaks (plus a UI for data entry). You may need to log off between changes for them to take effect.

Comment: Are you saying you want to control the keys while the program is inactive?

Comment: no just iwant change enter event ,In this way, when "Enter" is pressed, it acts as if a "tab" has been entered, even when the program is running, but I am typing in another window.